# Storing large pictures in iOS swift

Tags: ios, caching, swift3, uiimage

I am planning to ship an app with at least 20 pictures that can be at big as 10mb each. They are pictures that the user is likely to zoom in quite a bit therefore it is a requirement to keep the resolution quite high. We are still trying to make them smaller, but even so, its unlikely that they are going to be less than 7mb each.

The images can be shipped with the app as well as additional pictures can also be downloaded. The requirement is for the pictures to be available offline once the user downloads them as the app is to be used in remote areas by researchers.

What is the best mechanism to store them and how should I store them in iOS Swift 3?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with Swift3. Since assets have no relation to the  programming language. For this big files it would make sense to tiles. Demo here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

You can store your pictures in document directory of the app and store the path in SQLite DB.

Comment: How would you put the .sqlite file and its _SUPPORT file (the images references) in the document directory so it would be accessible at first launch?

Answer (score 2):

There are not rules but a set of best practices.
To store them I suggest you to save them directly into your resources, not Xcode image asset, this is because "image asset" can only be called with the `imageNamed:` method of `UIImage`, that has the side effect of cache images.
Then you can create a `plist` file with an array of image names, and fetch your info from here. If you need something more complicated there is Core Data, but I can't see an application of it with your spec.

> What is the size of an uncompressed image in memory?
>  An approx
>   equation `n_pixel_height * n_pixel_width * n_channels` in bytes (supposing 8 bit for channel)

If your images are about 10Mb in jpg they are compressed, thus means that they will take a huge amount of memory. memory on this kind of devices is a precious and short resource. 
If your app exceeds the memory limit, after a set of callback such as didReceiveMemoryWarning, if you don't free enough memory, you app will be killed.
Alway try on device in this case and not on simulator because the simulator use your mac resources.
Now how to handle big images?
You can use `CATiledLayer`, you can find a lot of tutorials online. `CATiledLayer` as the name suggest creates a tiles of layer, each tile should correspond at a piece of your image, and it draws them only when they are visible.
Unfortunately it draws asynchronously this means that your tiles can be shown not exactly at the same time, there some strategy to avoid that issue, one is explained in an apple [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html).  
Of course there is a problem that needs to be solved, how can I cut my large images into tiles?
You can do programmatically or provide them already cut as resources of your application